# How to set the variable values in ansible based on user entry on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible

Here is my exact requirement.

**In jenkins:**

User will choose the env parameters: **TEST** OR **DEV**

**In ansible playbook:**
I need to run the sed command based on the ENV type being selected.

```
- vars:
   environ1: "TEST"
   environ2: "PROD"

- command: sed -i "s/test.abc.com/"{{SITE_URL}}"/g" /home/ubuntu/mysql.sql
    when: '{{backup_from}}' == '{{environ1}}'

- command: sed -i "s/abc.com/"{{SITE_URL}}"/g" /home/ubuntu/mysql.sql
    when: '{{backup_from}}' == '{{environ2}}'
```

**ERROR:**

```
[0;31m     when: '{{backup_from}}' == '{{environ}}'[0m
[0;31m                             ^ here[0m
[0;31mWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with[0m
[0;31mmissing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they[0m
[0;31mstart a value. For instance:[0m
[0;31m[0m
[0;31m    with_items:[0m
[0;31m      - {{ foo }}[0m
[0;31m[0m
[0;31mShould be written as:[0m
[0;31m[0m
[0;31m    with_items:[0m
[0;31m      - "{{ foo }}"[0m
[0;31m[0m
Connection to 18.221.160.190 closed.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Consider using [templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems with quotes and indentation:

- if you start an argument in YAML with a quote, you must quote the whole YAML value (this is the reason for the error)
- `when` should be on the task indentation level
- argument of `when` should be a Jinja2 expression, no need to use braces inside (although it works with a warning)
- you cannot nest double quotes in the argument of `command`
- there is no need to use quotes around Jinja2 expressions `{{ ... }}` except for the case when the whole YAML value starts with a brace

```
tasks:
  - command: sed -i "s/test.abc.com/{{SITE_URL}}/g" /home/ubuntu/mysql.sql
    when: backup_from == environ1

  - command: sed -i "s/abc.com/{{SITE_URL}}/g" /home/ubuntu/mysql.sql
    when: backup_from == environ2
```

---

You might also consider writing this as a single task (if there are only two environment values possible):

```
tasks:
  - command: sed -i "{{ expression }}" /home/ubuntu/mysql.sql
    vars:
      expression: "{{ (backup_from == 'TEST') | ternary('s/test.abc.com/{{SITE_URL}}/g', 's/abc.com/"{{SITE_URL}}"/g') }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the entire command has to be without quotes, try with:

```
- vars:
   environ1: "TEST"
   environ2: "PROD"

- command: sed -i "s/test.abc.com/"{{SITE_URL}}"/g" /home/ubuntu/mysql.sql
    when: backup_from == environ1

- command: sed -i "s/abc.com/"{{SITE_URL}}"/g" /home/ubuntu/mysql.sql
    when: backup_from == environ2
```

Comment: `when` doesn't want mustaches.

Comment: @PaulHodges you're right, just updated the answer by removing it

Comment: Cool. With luck, that will satisfy whoever downvoted.